# can i use rust's match in python?

Tags: python, rust, match

i want to use rust match in python3,

instead of if...elif statement.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html

```
fn main() {
    let number = 13;
    // TODO ^ Try different values for `number`

    println!("Tell me about {}", number);
    match number {
        // Match a single value
        1 => println!("One!"),
        // Match several values
        2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 => println!("This is a prime"),
        // Match an inclusive range
        13...19 => println!("A teen"),
        // Handle the rest of cases
        _ => println!("Ain't special"),
    }

    let boolean = true;
    // Match is an expression too
    let binary = match boolean {
        // The arms of a match must cover all the possible values
        false => 0,
        true => 1,
        // TODO ^ Try commenting out one of these arms
    };

    println!("{} -> {}", boolean, binary);
}
```

Comment: The simplest answer is: no

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini yes, i know. but still want. waiting for python hacker..

Comment: This is not a feature request site :) You may want to send a proposal to the Python-Ideas mailing list, but please note that this feature has been discussed many times, e.g.: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2018-May/050283.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the hint, Andrea Corbellini.

i found that solution, there is [pampy](https://pypi.org/project/pampy/)

```
from pampy import match, _

def func(x):
    return match(x,
          1, "One!",
          # 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11, "This is a prime",     # not work
          # 2 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 11, "This is a prime", # not work
          2, "This is a prime",
          _, "Ain't special"
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("1: {}".format(func(1)))
    print("2: {}".format(func(2)))
    print("3: {}".format(func(3)))
    print("5: {}".format(func(5)))
    print("7: {}".format(func(7)))
    print("nothing: {}".format(func("nothing")))
```

--

EDIT: Now (2020/06), there is official draft for match [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/)

Comment: apparently it's difficult to be the first person to wish for something - somebody already has done it :) Good find @sailfish009, I thought at first it's not available.